# Can't Creating onCreate(Bundle) - TheNewBoston Tutorial 46

Tags: java, android

As usual I started a new class under "com.orkun.deneme" called "OpenedClass" as Travis said in the tutorial. Again as usual, I right click>Source>Override/Impliment Methods. There used to be a check button for onCreate(Bundle) under List Activity Tab. But this time there wasn't any Tab called List Activity. There is only a Tab called Object. So that I couldn't create onCreate(Bundle) method and I stuck at this tutorial. Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend `Activity`.

```
public class OpenedClass extends Activity{

}
```